# Rename something on Visual Studio (Not all code)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Think about code like this

```
    low = a.finder((dashtryBb + dashbtcA), (dashbtcA + dashbtcAa), btctryAa);

    if (low > btclow)
    {
    if (low > btclimit)
    {
    var a = buy.Order("DASHBTC", Math.Round(btclimit / dashbtcA, 8, MidpointRounding.ToZero), dashbtcA);
    var b = buy.Order("DASHTRY", Math.Round(btclimit / dashbtcA, 8, MidpointRounding.ToZero), btctryA);
    var c = buy.Order("BTCTRY", Math.Round(Math.Round(btclimit / dashbtcA, 8, MidpointRounding.ToZero) * dashbtcA, 8, MidpointRounding.ToZero), dashtryB);                             
    }
```

I want to change all small **"dash"** to different word sth like **"eos"** but in spesific area not all code.
Example

```
low = a.finder((eostryBb + eosbtcA), (eosbtcA + eosbtcAa), btctryAa);

    if (low > btclow)
    {
    if (low > btclimit)
    {
    var a = buy.Order("DASHBTC", Math.Round(btclimit / eosbtcA, 8, MidpointRounding.ToZero), eosbtcA);
    var b = buy.Order("DASHTRY", Math.Round(btclimit / eosbtcA, 8, MidpointRounding.ToZero), btctryA);
    var c = buy.Order("BTCTRY", Math.Round(Math.Round(btclimit / eosbtcA, 8, MidpointRounding.ToZero) * eosbtcA, 8, MidpointRounding.ToZero), eostryB);                             
    }
```

I have tried rename on right click but its changing every **"dash"** not only in function.
Any help apreciated.

Comment: Where are they defined?  If you do a rename it's going to rename it everywhere.

Comment: You can toggle the filters (find and replace) as needed - full word, match case, etc. You can also apply the change for the currently selected (highlighted) block of code  - `Selection` in the dropdown options. Hth

Comment: @juharr not trying to change variable, i wanna use same code on different functions with different variable.

Comment: What they are saying is that VS _can_ make the change for you to ensure that whatever uses that variable is also updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename is *meant* to do it everywhere, that is precisely why it exists.

For this case you can make a text selection of the small area that is to be altered, then do a regular "Find & Replace" with "Selection" enabled:

[image: replace dialog]

And then probably with the *Match case* switch toggled on.

Answer (score 1):

If using the "rename" refactoring, then Visual Studio is correctly recognizing where a name like `dashtryBb` is used in multiple places to refer to the same thing. If you understand this but want to actually *change the meaning of your code* in this spot, use the textual [find and replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

### Advanced fastest typing approach:--

Press Alt + C to toggle case sensitive search or case insensitive search.
After that select the text you want to find and replace and press Ctrl + D to do Multiline editing of similar selected texts..
keep on clicking Ctrl + D to move down as per your requirements....